# $limit number of documents in $lookup

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I encounter a problem with this query that returns this result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd22f28f77cfb1f6ce503ca"),
    "search" : "flarize",
    "name" : "flarize",
    "color" : 0,
    "profil" : "",
    "banner" : "",
    "desc" : "",
    "date" : 1540501286109,
    "friend" : [
            [        
                    {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bd22f28f77cfb1f6ce503ca"),
                            "search" : "flarize",
                            "name" : "flarize",
                            "email" : "flarize.b73@gmail.com",
                            "password" : "$2a$10$eYeOtEkEUyD7TFkjKvhZOuSSpvBolkL17TrPHuoHhOT8JrsQR0UKW",
                            "color" : 0,
                            "profil" : "",
                            "banner" : "",
                            "desc" : "",
                            "date" : 1540501286109,
                            "friend" : [
                                    {
                                            "id" : ObjectId("5bd22f28f77cfb1f6ce503ca"),
                                            "date" : 1540572026419
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "id" : ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b6"),
                                            "date" : 1540572026419
                                    }
                            ],
                            "groupes" : [ ]
                    }
            ]
    ]
}
```

But it's not really what I want, I'd like these fields to be hidden: friend.password, friend.email and the result of friend.groups and friend.friend is limité to 10. I don't know how i can solve this problem. My request :

```
db.users.aggregate(
    {$match:
        {search:"flarize"}
    },
    {$lookup:
        {from:"users", 
         localField:"friend.id", 
         foreignField:"_id", 
         as:"friend"
    }},
    {$project:
        { search: 1, 
         name: 1, 
         profil: 1, 
         banner: 1, 
         color: 1, 
         date: 1, 
         desc: 1, 
         friend: [{$slice:["$friend", 0, 10]}]
    }
}).pretty();
```

One document of users:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd22f28f77cfb1f6ce503ca"),
    "search" : "flarize",
    "name" : "flarize",
    "email" : "theo.ba73@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$eYeOtEkEUyD7TFkjKvhZOuSSpvBolkL17TrPHuoHhOT8JrsQR0UKW",
    "color" : 0,
    "profil" : "",
    "banner" : "",
    "desc" : "",
    "date" : 1540501286109,
    "friend" : [
            {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5bd22f28f77cfb1f6ce503ca"),
                    "date" : 1540572026419
            },
            {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5bd19a92da24674fdabd26b6"),
                    "date" : 1540572026419
            }
    ],
    "groupes" : [ ]
 }
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Could you show your sample documents and the version of mongo you are using.

Comment: why u r doing lookup with users you are aggregating with users also.

Comment: 4.0.3 for version and for Kuldeep Mishra i don't know there is a others way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $match: { search: "flarize" } },
  { $lookup: {
    from: "users", 
    let: { friendId: "$friend.id" }, 
    pipeline: [
      { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$friendId"] }}},
      { $limit: 10 },
      { $project: { email: 0, password: 0 }}
    ], 
    as: "friend"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Now friend field is empty